# Stop CountDownTimer when we click on the home button

Tags: java, android

How do I stop the CountDownTimer when I leave the application (when I click on the home button on my smartphone) the CountDownTimer remains running
  I tried with this code but when I leave the application a message appears in my smartphone "app name has stopped." Close the application
help me please
here is the code that I use

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText(String.format("%d : %d ",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_cum, null);
                    TextView title = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    TextView message = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.message);
                    ImageView icone = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.icone);

                    title.setText("Result");
                    icone.setImageResource(R.drawable.smile_lost);
                    message.setText("You have exceeded \n your time of reflection");

                    builder1.setPositiveButton("Replay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            finish();
                            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                    builder1.setView(view1);
                    builder1.setCancelable(false);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog1 = builder1.create();
                    alertDialog1.show();
                }


        }.start();
}
```

is the code in onStop ()

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: did you try timer.cancel ?

Comment: remove @RequiresApi annotation and use timer.cancel() method

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two way

**1**

Create global variable like

```
private isInForgrand = false;
```

And in onStop() or onPause() and onResume() change it

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    isInForgrand = false;
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isInForgrand = true;
}
```

And in onFinish() check it

```
@Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(isInForgrand){
               //do what you want  
             }else{
               //your app NOT in Forgrannd
        }
```

**2**

You can cancel CountDownTimer in onStop()

```
@Override
public void onStop() { 
    super.onStop();
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
}
```